# Is 256 a reasonable length for a Diffie-Hellman safe prime?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-size

There's a program that uses the following OpenSSL function...

```
DH_generate_parameters(256, 5, NULL, NULL)
```

...to create DH parameters which are later used for hundreds of key exchanges (and the one-time keys used to encrypt login details sent over Internet).

The manual page says 256 is `prime_len` in bits. **How secure is this value?** (I have a bad feeling.)

Also, if I'm reading http://www.keylength.com/, does this correspond to "discrete logarithm *key*" or "discrete logarithm *group*" or am I looking in the entirely wrong place?

Comment: By the way, you don't *need* to generate your own parameters. You can use, for example, `get_rfc3526_prime_2048` to load some [standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3526) ones.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing whoever made the program was confused about key lengths. A 256-bit DH modulus will not give 256-bits of security. It will provide far less.

If you're reading http://www.keylength.com, the value here corresponds to the "discrete logarithm group". These days you really want a minimum of 2048 bits.

Comment: OP asked about a _safe prime_. in particular, the group order is (one bit less than) the modulus. what's your basis here for "far less"?